# How to change default settings for Text to Columns Wizard for CSV documents

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

Is there a way to change the default settings for 'Text to Columns Wizard' from 'Fixed width' to 'Delimited' when working with CSV documents?

[image: Text to Columns Wizard]

Currently I have to manually change it every time I open the wizard.

Comment: Here's a not-so-useful answer... Upgrade to 2016! It seems the default for 2016 (at least on my system where I haven't tried to change the default) is set to Delimited.

Comment: The department I work for only has an enterprise licence for Microsoft Office 2013.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to change the default settings for the Text to Columns wizard.

Excel just seems to fail at detecting if the data is delimited or fixed width when any row has spaces within the values. Eg "value1 value1, value2 value2".

Answer (score 0):

use Microsoft's [Get & Transform](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Get-Transform-in-Excel-2016-881c63c6-37c5-4ca2-b616-59e18d75b4de) *power tools* for parsing data from a csv file.
(For Excel 2010-2013, use the free MS add-in [Power Query for Excel](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=39379).)

It's much more efficient for importing data as the old fashioned "From Text wizard".
According [Microsoft](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/unified-get-transform-experience-ad78befd-eb1c-4ea7-a55d-79d1d67cf9b3) the Power Query way replaces it:

> With this connector you can easily import data from your text (*.txt),
>   comma-separated values (*.csv) or formatted text (*.prn) files. This
>   modern connector is based on Power Query technology, and replaces the
>   legacy From Text wizard.